# Redshift UNLOAD JSON

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to directly export a JSON file to S3 from Redshift using UNLOAD?  I'm not seeing anything in the documentation ([Redshift UNLOAD documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)), but maybe I'm missing something. 
 The COPY command supports downloading JSON, so I'm surprised that there's not JSON flag for UNLOAD.

For more context:
I'm loading data from one Redshift instance to another, but the respective tables have different column orders, and I need to respect the column order in the destination.  Seems like the best way to do this is to work with a serialization format that doesn't care about column order.

Comment: no, there is not a way to unload as json unfortunately. however why do you want to unload as json? why not just unload as csv but specify the right (destination) column order in your unload statement?

Comment: What are you using to move the data? Just UNLOAD/LOAD commands? If you are using Python you can load data into a dataframe, reorder and load into target Redshift

Comment: You can specify a different _column-list_ in the `COPY` command that loads the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unload to a JSON file is not possible with UNLOAD command in Redshift.

[How to dump data from Redshift to JSON | DevelByte](https://sikandar89dubey.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/how-to-dump-data-from-redshift-to-json/) claims there is a workaround, I haven't tried it, but it might give you an idea.

Comment: what if i want to dump json as :
{"key1" : 1}
instead of:
{"key1":"1"}

Comment: it's now supported with Redshift Unload

Comment: @HarryDuong: i'm working on a student data and in my database there is a row for each subject that student enrolls, when I export to a JSON, I want all the subjects as a list . For eg: Student 1 : Subjects :{"Maths", "English" } etc

Comment: @NK7983, check out `listagg`. You can use it to build a string like JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Unload as json is supported by Redshift now.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html#unload-examples-json

Example from AWS doc

```
unload ('select * from venue')
to 's3://mybucket/unload/' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
JSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use at the end of the query FORMAT JSON;

AWS Blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/export-json-data-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-redshift-unload/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).